# How to UV unwrap walls in archimesh?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to create a room using the archimesh addon and I'm having difficulty in getting the material to apply to the walls properly.  I want to UV unwrap all the walls separately so they fit the wooden image texture I have applied.  However, as you can see from the image I rendered below, only one wall worked properly.  Also, I was not able to subdivide the other walls (faces).  Does anyone know where I might be going wrong?

[image: room]

Here is a screenshot of the wall I am trying to work on:

[image]

Here's a shot of what it looks like when I try to unwrap:

[image]

Here's the .blend

[image]